how could "libreoffice --convert-to pdf" with Excel grid borderline?
Just as the title, there's also people ask at https://ask.libreoffice.org/t/how-to-print-xlsx-excel-file-with-grid-borderline/36607

I need to print xlsx using command line. This is the command I use.
libreoffice --headless --print-to-file output.ps example.xlsx  
ps2pdf output.ps output.pdf

I first print to ps then convert to PDF, but the file
printed does not have a grid borderline. Is there a way to include a
borderline in the print? Note, I don't want a GUI solution, only a CLI solution.

